# How to construct a point by a pointer in one line?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a Point constructor which accepts a double pointer. I do it as following

```
Point::Point(double* p)
   : mX(p[0]), mY(p[1]), mZ(p[2])
{}

Point pt( []() -> double* {double p[3] = {1, 2, 3}; return p;}() );
```

Any easier way to construct a pointer in one line with specified values?

Comment: The code you have pasted invokes undefined behavior, as you use a pointer to a stack-allocated value after the function that contains that value has returned.  Further, we don't know what the `Point` constructor is going to do with this pointer (does it extract the values and then discard the pointer, or does it retain the pointer and `delete[]` it later?) and so we can't reliably suggest an alternative.  You might consider writing a new constructor for this particular case.

Comment: I add the constructor. And the class is in a 3rd party library thus I don't want to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to declare a local array and pass a pointer to that:

```
double p[3] = {1, 2, 3};
Point pt(p);
```

Alternatively, consider writing a new constructor that lets you pass the three coordinates directly:

```
Point::Point(double x, double y, double z)
    : mX(x), mY(y), mZ(z)
{ }
```

If adding a constructor is not possible then you could use a factory:

```
Point make_point(double x, double y, double z)
{
    double p[3] = { x, y, z };

    return Point(p);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[EDIT] This creates the temporary array on the stack, so it will be a lot faster that the other two options, which involve a memory allocation (`new` / `delete`):

```
Point pt( &(double[3]){1, 2, 3}[0] );
```

To avoid a memory leak and actually return a pointer, you have to make it somewhat longer:

```
Point pt( std::unique_ptr<double>(
    []() -> double* { return new double[3]{1, 2, 3}; }()
    ).get() );
```

Another option:

```
Point pt( std::vector<double>{1,2,3}.data() );
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not work: the array returned from the lambda function is destroyed after returning from the lambda but before passing it on to the constructor where you want to see it. The code probably appears to work but that is just the worst case of undefined behavior.

Personally, I think you should consider a better interface. If you can't change your interface, you might want to use something like this:

```
typedef double array[3];
Point pt(&(array{ 1.2, 2.3, 3.4 })[0]);
```